# Does accessing via a shared_ptr pollute the cache line more than raw pointer?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, shared-ptr

I understand a good compiler can perform optimization so that accessing, say an `int*` via a `std::shared_ptr` is done using the same assembly as if a raw `int*` pointer was used.

My question is: would the cache line containing the optimized smart pointer be polluted with other data members from the smart pointer, like the reference counter? So that although the assembly generated would be identical with a real pointer, the cache performance could be worse because not as much of the cache line is being used efficiently?

EDIT: This performance effect could be more-noticeable if we were iterating through a structure like `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>` and using the ints.

Answer (score 4):

There are several things to consider, but in summary one can say: It doesn't really matter.

First, there is no guarantee (or rather, no *requirement*) that there is a reference counter at all. It is merely required which way `std::shared_ptr` has to behave. Using a reference counter is one way of achieving this,  circular-linked-list being another.
Practically, all implementations (all *that I know of*, at least) do use a reference counter.

Second, the reference counter can be allocated separately via `operator new` or in the same location and using the same allocation as the managed object (which is created via placement `new`) if you use `make_shared`. The latter is, again, not strictly guaranteed. The standard states *"Implementations are **encouraged**, but not required, to perform no more than one memory allocation"*, explicitly allowing something different

If the reference counter is separately allocated, then it will most likely live in a different cache line, and so the system will consume two cache lines rather than one when accessing the object. That, however, is in some situations an *advantage*, not a disadvantage (that is, whenever you copy the smart pointer, see below).
In addition to the data cache, there exists also the TLB, which is much smaller (usually less than 64 entries). Given that there is a certain likelihood that two separately allocated objects will not only be in different cache lines but in different memory pages, this may be another thing that will cost a few extra cycles.

If the reference counter is allocated in the same location, it will very likely be in the same cache line as the beginning of the object (but it might be in the previous cache line as well). This looks like an advantage, but it is not necessarily one.

Whenever the `shared_ptr` is copied or one smart pointer referencing the same object goes out of scope, the reference counter must be modified. This is a write to the cache line the counter lives in (or rather, since it's an atomic operation, **not** a write to the cache line, but the net effect to the outside world is the same). The cache line is invalidated and must be fetched again by everybody else wanting to access it.
There exists a common problem known as "false sharing" where naive parallel processing runs much slower than everybody would expect, which occurs for that exact same reason.

Now if the reference counter is allocated together with the object, this means that whenever the shared pointer is copied (or goes out of scope) the next access to the object is a guaranteed cache miss (since the cache line containing the start of the object will be purged from cache).

### tl;dr

Yes, there are cache effects, however, you should not worry too much. Cache misses happen all the time, and regularly (the same goes for the TLB). As long as you have at least a somewhat coherent access pattern, this will not matter at all.
After the next context switch (that is, every few milliseconds, or after the next interrupt or syscall) your cache and TLB will likely be gone anyway. That's something everyone has to live with, and it's not a problem at all.

You do not use a `shared_ptr` for fun, but because it provides a valuable functionality that you need. Copying the pointer might be 3-4 cycles slower than copying a raw pointer, and it might cause an occasional extra cache miss when you copy it, but you *don't* make a hundred thousand copies per second.

The safety and overall utility benefits by far outweight the disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

**I have good reasons to believe that you are worrying about the wrong thing.**

Consider the following two snippets:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> v = { std::make_shared<int>(1), 
                                          std::make_shared<int>(2),
                                          std::make_shared<int>(3) };
  for (auto& e : v)
    std::printf("%d\n", *e);
}
```

and the same functionality but with `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
  v.reserve(3);
  v.emplace_back(make_unique<int>(1));
  v.emplace_back(make_unique<int>(2));
  v.emplace_back(make_unique<int>(3));
  for (auto& e : v)
    std::printf("%d\n", *e);
}
```

Just to answer your question:

> This performance effect could be more-noticeable if we were iterating through a structure 
>   like `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>` and using the `int`s.

Here are the corresponding loops:

```
    shared_ptr version   |    unique_ptr version
.L66:                    | .L70:
    movq    (%rbx), %rax |    movq    (%rbx), %rax
    movl    $.LC0, %esi  |    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi     |    movl    $1, %edi
    movl    (%rax), %edx |    movl    (%rax), %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax   |    xorl    %eax, %eax
.LEHB2:                  |.LEHB6:
    call    __printf_chk |    call    __printf_chk
.LEHE2:                  |.LEHE6:
    addq    $16, %rbx    |    addq    $8, %rbx
    cmpq    %rbx, %rbp   |    cmpq    %rbx, %rbp
    jne    .L66          |    jne    .L70
```

The only relevant difference is that you are doing larger steps with `shared_ptr` when reading the memory. In both cases the memory access pattern if linear with fixed stride length. **I failed to come up with a scenario where there is any measurable difference between the two.**

In my opinion, that answers your question.

---

**Some unsolicited advice**, just to show you that you are worrying about the wrong thing. Analyze the generated assembly code for the two code snippets above (`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fwhole-program -O3 -S` and run the assembly through `c++filt`). You will find out that `shared_ptr` is a heavy weight object compared to `unique_ptr`. You will see that it is very expensive to construct and destroy `shared_ptr`s, and to maintain the atomic reference counts; you will pay for the heavy weight multi-threading machinery as well.

I know it is a questionable metric but the assembly code for `shared_ptr` is 740 lines, and the code for the `unique_ptr` is 402 lines. If you analyze the construction and destruction of the objects, you will notice that significantly more code is executed for `shared_ptr` ***and*** many of those instructions are more expensive (expensive multi-threading stuff). `shared_ptr` also consumes more memory for the extra bookkeeping (on these silly code snippets: 144 vs. 36 bytes, that is, 4 times more with `shared_ptr`).

Potential cache misses would be the last thing that I would worry about at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying the smart pointer (so that the reference count needs to be modified) it will certainly be brought into cache for the update.  The problem associated with that can be mitigated if you use `std::make_shared` as that ensures that the reference count and the target object are allocated in a single allocation.

Comment: That's not _quite_ what the question was asking, but the answer he wanted is in here too.

Comment: @Chad I think this refers to the time of creating the shared_ptr, not the time accessing it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the implementation of `shared_ptr` will require more than just the raw pointer as a member. C++ is not always required to keep members contiguous, but in most cases it will. Thus if a cache line is larger than a pointer (as it is in most architectures) some part of the cache line will be unused and the cache will be less efficient as a result.

Comment: A cache line is currently 64 bytes and on a 64-bit OS a pointer is 8 bytes? So we have 7 remaining bytes? I am asking how many of these remaining 7 bytes are used up by shared_ptr "internals"?

Comment: @user997112 I have trouble understanding your math, it would be 7 *pointers* worth or 56 bytes. It should be possible to fit more than one `shared_ptr` into a cache line of that size. My point was that it's not necessary to know the exact implementation details, you know there's going to be a performance hit even if you can't quantify it.

Comment: Sorry I meant 7 remaining 64-bit sections- so 56 bytes. You say you know there's going to be a performance hit- but I don't know that, that's what I am asking.

Comment: @user997112 if it really matters to you and is not just idle curiosity, the only way to know is to measure. If the cache is large enough to hold all your active data you might not notice a difference even if it's only half as effective.